# error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm creating a simple flaskapp which I'm going to deploy on heroku, first time deploying a python app on heroku, with that said i'm new to gunicorn.

Addtitional notes: Using a virtual environment.

Version of flask Flask==0.10.1

gunicorn==19.3.0

Using 'python run.py' **works**

Using 'foreman start' I get the following error

```
16:35:44 web.1  | started with pid 4047
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4047] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4047] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4047)
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4047] [INFO] Using worker: sync
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4053] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4053
16:35:44 web.1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4053] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
16:35:44 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
16:35:44 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
16:35:44 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
16:35:44 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
16:35:44 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
16:35:44 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
16:35:44 web.1  |     __import__(module)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/SoftwareEng/barcodeServer/SoftwareEng/run.py", line 3, in <module>
16:35:44 web.1  |     flaskapp.run(debug=True)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
16:35:44 web.1  |     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 617, in run_simple
16:35:44 web.1  |     test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
16:35:44 web.1  |     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
16:35:44 web.1  | error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
16:35:44 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
16:35:44 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
16:35:44 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
16:35:44 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
16:35:44 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
16:35:44 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
16:35:44 web.1  |     __import__(module)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/SoftwareEng/barcodeServer/SoftwareEng/run.py", line 3, in <module>
16:35:44 web.1  |     flaskapp.run(debug=True)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
16:35:44 web.1  |     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/test/SoftwareEng/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 617, in run_simple
16:35:44 web.1  |     test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
16:35:44 web.1  |     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
16:35:44 web.1  | error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4053] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4053)
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4047] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
16:35:44 web.1  | [2015-03-30 16:35:44 +0000] [4047] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
16:35:44 web.1  | exited with code 3
16:35:44 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn run:flaskapp --log-file=-
```

File Structure

```
/
 ...
 run.py
 Procfile
 app/
    __init__.py
    routes.py
    ...
```

run.py

```
from app import flaskapp
flaskapp.run(debug=True)
```

__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask

flaskapp = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

routes.py

```
from app import flaskapp
from flask import render_template
import dbwrapper

@flaskapp.route('/')
@flaskapp.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

From what I read gunicorn allows for the creation of multiple threads, which leads me to think that the threads are trying to access the same port which throws the **already in use error**. However I have no idea how to resolve it, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you're calling run:flaskapp instead of app:flaskapp and run.py is trying to open another instance.

```
16:35:44 web.1  |   File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/SoftwareEng/barcodeServer/SoftwareEng/run.py", line 3, in <module>
```

First, always encapsulate the run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flaskapp.run(debug=True)
```

And update your procfile to call the `app.__init__.py` instead:

```
web: gunicorn app:flaskapp --log-file=-
```

PS: I don't know what procfile or foreman are -- heroku things?

Comment: the procfile is a file that is used to specify what commands you want run
best stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670186/launching-an-app-in-heroku-what-is-procfile-web-command)
The foreman is specific to the toolbelt i installed for heroku, it uses the procfile to start the app

Comment: figured. let me know if the proposed fix addressed the issue.

Comment: I just needed to add the


            if \__name\__ == '\__main\__':

and it worked, thanks alot