# Python Heroku app fails with "Address in use" error

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Have deployed a basic python/flask app in Heroku (code below). As far as Im aware the procfile is correct and the requirements are up to date. 
The application basically receives two arguments through the browser and returns JSON. I am relatively new to heroku and procfiles so I am worried it is something simple.

But I get this error in my logs once I try to open the link in a browser:

> OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Is my procfile correct?

Please find the code below for reference:

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn SA2:SAapp
```

Python code:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import tweepy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from flask import Flask
import json

SAapp = Flask("Sentwinel")

#Function that collects the percentages
def percentage(part, whole):
    return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)

#Setting variables for the auth information that allows us to access twitters API
consumerKey = "3DOvT3TjEgd16Yk7xvNxNjUMQ"
consumerSecret = "DeMxglGqNdO9A1xwE8PfI4IMTPFnL6jAihxunsA45zlxfwW9bk"
accessToken = "381544613-Zda1F8KbIZ0q1Eyz1azIpllKu9eimHaUkJNZpioa"
accessTokenSecret = "GwtenTAoU3Bki2F1MvnbNRxm3XahX0O8vRx8eFqC8SVoR"

#Connects to the twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#The function that gets the search terms and returns the SA
@SAapp.route("/<searchTerm>/<noOfSearchTerms>")
def GetPlot (searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
    noOfSearchTerms = int(noOfSearchTerms)
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm).items(noOfSearchTerms)

    positive = 0
    negative = 0
    neutral = 0
    polarity = 0

    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity

        if (analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0):
            neutral += 1
        elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity < 0.00):
            negative += 1
        elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0.00):
            positive += 1

    #Shows the percentages of how many tweets per emotion per how many search terms.
    positive = percentage(positive, noOfSearchTerms)
    negative = percentage(negative, noOfSearchTerms)
    neutral = percentage(neutral, noOfSearchTerms)
    polarity = percentage(polarity, noOfSearchTerms)

    #Formats the polarity to show to 2 decimal places
    #positive = format(positive, '.2f')
    #negative = format(negative, '.2f')
    #neutral = format(neutral, '.2f')

    print("How people are reacting on " + searchTerm + "by analyzing" + str(noOfSearchTerms) + " Tweets.")
    if (polarity == 0 ):
        print("Neutral")
    elif (polarity < 0.00 ):
        print("Negative")
    elif (polarity > 0.00 ):
        print("Postitive")

    #Returns the polarity scores as JSON integers, for Android Studio
    return json.dumps({"positive":positive,"negative":negative,"neutral":neutral})


SAapp.run()
```

Comment: Is this running locally? Please show exactly what you typed to get that error.

Comment: This is when i hit "heroku open", or open the link to the app in the browser, after I have deployed the application to heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some late night research, I finally found the solution. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356224/error-errno-98-address-already-in-use) SO question.

The problem was not in the procfile, but in the python/flask code. I needed to add encapsulation to the flask app.

I changed this line:

```
SAapp = Flask("Sentwinel")
```

To this:

```
SAapp = Flask(__name__)
```

And added this line:

```
if __name__ == "main":
```

above my SAapp.run().

Wanted to add in case anybody ran into the same problem